# Programs crashing on WIN11 after creating Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot

I installed Ubuntu on my PC in a dual boot setup with Win 11 (which I have used solo in the past).

I am having issues with programs (steam, chrome, steam games and discord) crashing or not starting ever since. The only similar forum entry I found was this: [after installing linux in dual boot many of programs crashes on windows 7 64](https://superuser.com/questions/96890/after-installing-linux-in-dual-boot-many-of-programs-crashes-on-windows-7-64?newreg=ae0a2845acd04f01833de9f8e6673cf7)

But it's 13 years old and therefore didn't help much. I tried sfc /scannow reinstalled the programs and even did a rollback to a previous win update. I also updated drivers but nothing helped.

I am wondering if my partition setup might be the cause, as something like that was mentioned in the linked question. [This is my setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1CW7.jpg)

Disk1: The big one is for windows. The 4gb and the two 22gb partitions are for linux. (/ and /home and swap)
I think the

Disk0: is used by win but there's nothing of relevance on it.

Do you think the partition setup is at fault? And if so, how can I make it better?

Thank you
Leo

Comment: Is there an issue with UEFI and Secure Boot? Windows 11 enforces these settings

Comment: Hi John, what would an issue with UEFI look like? Secure boot is disabled, should I enable it?

Comment: @Leo Why is Secure Boot disabled _(there is only a limited use case for disabling it)_? Do you have CSM [Legacy] Mode enabled? Are you fully shutting down Windows before booting to Ubuntu _(hibernate/sleep cannot be used - is Fast Startup enabled within the UEFI firmware settings?)_?

Comment: Ana again, Windows 11 requires Secure Boot enabled. That is very likely the root cause of your current problems. **Dual-booting never is!** This notwithstanding any problem with the partitioning - very likely - but that only affects Ubuntu. And, as above, when dual-booting the Windows Fast Startup feature must be disabled.

Comment: I have Windows 11 Pro here and run Ubuntu extremely well as a Virtual Machine using VMware. I suggest that here.